# Cassandra DB schema for Vehicle telemetry data

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql, schema

Use case : Vehicles are running on the field and they keep sending telemetry data like temperature, lat, longitude and speed. I have to build a system to keep this data and serve analytic queries like How many vehicles over sped, total distance covered by each vehicle- daily, monthly , yearly, send alert in case of over speeding

I am planning to use Cassandra to keep the vehicle data

```
   CREATE TABLE vehicle_data_by_day  (

   vehicle_id VARCHAR,
   vehicle_number               VARCHAR static,
   speed        INT,
    latitude                DOUBLE,
    longitude               DOUBLE
    year INT,
     month INT,
    day INT,
     time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((vehicle_id, year, month, day), time)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
   AND compaction = {'class': 'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 
                'compaction_window_size': 1, 
                'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS'};
```

For serving analytic queries , I will populate the below table by running a back ground job  by querying the vehicle_data_by_day at a certain frequency

```
   create table vehicle_report (
    vehicle_id                    VARCHAR,
   vehicle_number               VARCHAR static ,
   distance_covered_per_day    int,
   year INT,
   month INT,
   day INT,
   PRIMARY KEY ((vehicle_id, year, month, day), 
   distance_covered_per_day)
   )
   WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (distance_covered_per_day DESC);
   AND compaction = {'class': 'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 
                'compaction_window_size': 1, 
                'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS'};

                select distance_covered_per_day from vehicle_report where vehicle_id = ka01 and vehicle_type=car
```

will this design scale or I am better using an analytic DB ?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use Cassandra as your only database, but more of a first-level/edge data store. How is the background job working in this system?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many readings are taken during a single day.  But from a data distribution and scaling standpoint, this looks good to me.  It does look like it could be difficult to query (only by exact date), but yes, that is the tradeoff.

Typically, Cassandra isn't a good solution for OLAP based queries, which usually require some dynamic query parameters.  But as long as the 2nd table can be queried without using the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive, it should be fine.